# Why blanch handcut fries?

Tags: potatoes, french-fries, blanching

I work at a restaurant. Im a potential management candidate. One of my first projects is researching hand cut fries in an effort to transition from pre-cut fries to making our fries in house. I guess my question is a little more specific than why the process is done but rather would the process differ based on the type of potato used, say prep for russet burbank vs yukon gold?

thanks guys.

Comment: Hallo Xavier. A hint: our system pulls all older questions similar to yours and displays them in the sidebar, in the "Related" column. Most of them explain the effects of blanching, go through them.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/8477/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20223/67

Answer (score 2):

When I was working as a cook, we did this to cook the potatoes enough so that we would have a better result after deep frying. Deep frying alone can make for a fry that is not always cooked through to the center. If you blanche, or par-boil, the potatoes ahead of time, some advantages are these.

- Frying goes more quickly, because the potatoes are partially cooked
- The fries are more evenly cooked, because you don’t have to rely on
  the deep fryer to do all the cooking

Probably not an thorough list of advantages, but these are the biggies.

If you go to hand cut fires, make sure cut the size you go with is consistent. This make of a better deep frying experience.

You can also deep fry potatoes at a low temperature (300 degrees F) for some time as an alternative to blanching.

Comment: Additionally, if you blanch the hand-cut fries and then freeze them for quick cooking later, that dries them out a bit more and makes the interiors fluffier.